# Are there any dice games you can play with a standard 7-die set?

Tags: game-design, recommendations, mechanics, dice

Are there any dice games that you can play with a standard role-playing 7-die set (d4, d6, d8, d10, d%, d12, d20)?

Maybe you have some time to kill before your tabletop session starts, or during a break. It'd be nice to have a game that doesn't require anything beyond this set of dice. I'm open to games that can be played alone or with friends.

This is an offshoot from another question: [Is there a name for the standard 7-die set?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39546/is-there-a-name-for-the-standard-7-die-set) I recently received a [very nice set of dice](http://www.shapeways.com/model/126266/thorn-dice-set-with-decader.html) as an anniversary gift. I'm not currently in a tabletop session, but I would like to play with the dice.

Comment: Are you looking for something where the *entirety* of the game only requires one 7-dice set, or would one-set-per-player be acceptable?

Comment: @PaulMarshall Either option is acceptable.

Comment: *sigh* Why even bother with a game-recommendation tag then? It's not a subjective opinion question, and it doesn't seem like there's a plethora of answers to it. I haven't used a "community wiki" answer before, but would that help make this more relevant to SE?

Comment: @redlamp If you look at the tag description it says "Ask Question
Do Not Use Generally off-topic. Suggestions for games that meet specific requirements. (tag exists primarily for historical reasons)", for more info on why they are no longer considered on-topic you can see the linked meta post.

Answer (score 3):

With 2-3 sets, you could play [Button Men](https://cheapass.com/free-games/button-men/), a Cheapass Game about capturing dice. Lots of entirely free characters available.

Comment: I love Button Men and recommend it as an RPG game day filler during a store run or the like.

Answer (score 1):

How about http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34947/dice-the-evolution ?  I've never tried it but you only need to print out 1 page of paper to give it a shot :)